# How to use both Omniauth_callbacks controller and custom devise registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise, omniauth

I have a custom registrations controller for devise set up, which is this:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}
```

and in the controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
      user_path(resource)
    end
end
```

It works great.

However I also have omniauth authentication, which again works great...by itself:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
        if user.persisted?
        flash.notice = "Signed in!"
        sign_in_and_redirect user
        else
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
        redirect_to sign_up_path
        end
  end
    alias_method :linkedin, :all
    alias_method :twitter, :all

end
```

However as you can probably already see my problem - I'm not sure how to get them to work together, as they both start with 'devise_for :users' and so whichever way round I place them in the routes file, one won't work.

How can I get them both working at the same time, so that the registrations controller only overrides the 'edit' and 'update' actions, while the omniauth_callbacks controller handles authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In routes.rb, you can put comma seperated paths for `devise_for` like this -

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations", omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

This will work.